# Mosquitto broker reporting local IP connection as external IP address

Tags: mosquitto

I have mosquitto broker v2.0.18 running on my local machine (Mac) 192.168.1.10. Everything appears to connect OK but I notice that one of my local IoT devices is being reported as connecting from my external IP address ( Internet provider address 120.nnn.nnn.nnn) but the IoT device is configured to connect via IP 192.168.1.10

mosquitto output:

```
1697605251: New connection from 120.nnn.nnn.nnn:56926 on port 1883.  
1697605346: Client <unknown> has exceeded timeout, disconnecting.  
1697605347: New connection from 120.nnn.nnn.nnn:56926 on port 1883.
```

And whilst it connects and works for a few minutes, it gets disconnected due to timeout.

mosquitto.conf setting:

```
listener 1883 0.0.0.0
```

I have a port forward rule on my home router that forwards port nnnn to 1883 on my local machine that remote IoT devices use and works OK. I note that this rule is causing the local connection to be reported as external, if I remove the port forward rule from my router the local connection works as expected, but now the remotes can't connect!

Any advice on port forward/mosquitto setup would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a work around by adding another listener to mosquitto on a different port and then pointing the local device to 192.168.1.10:

I am not familiar with network routing and port forward rules enough to know if the single port option should work, I do find it strange that the router swaps out the local IP for the external.